# Should I DELETE/UPDATE millions of rows via a row by row stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a `contacts` table which has about 200 million rows. I am using a stored procedure to UPDATE/DELETE the rows one by one, which is taking too long.

The procedure that DELETEs rows is the following one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `scrub_dnc_contacts`(vPhonebookId INT)
 proc:BEGIN

 DECLARE vContactId   BIGINT;
 DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;

 DECLARE contact_list CURSOR FOR
   SELECt c.id FROM contacts c 
        INNER JOIN contacts_tmp ct 
            ON c.contact = ct.contact 
                WHERE phonebook_id = vPhonebookId AND (ct.reachable = 0 OR ct.dnc_contact = 1) ;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
  SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

  OPEN contact_list;
  contact_loop: LOOP

  FETCH contact_list INTO vContactId;

  IF no_more_rows THEN
     CLOSE contact_list;
     LEAVE contact_loop;
  END IF;

  DELETE FROM contacts 
        WHERE id = vContactId;

 END LOOP contact_loop;
```

**My question**

How I can speed up this process, maybe UPDATE/DELETE the rows in a bulk operation or any other option?

Comment: Try hard to avoid cursors.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could delete all the records matching `vPhoneBookId` with a single query:

```
DELETE contacts 
  FROM contacts
    INNER JOIN contacts_tmp 
        ON contacts.contact = contacts_tmp.contact 
 WHERE phonebook_id = vPhonebookId
   AND (contacts_tmp.reachable = 0 OR contacts_tmp.dnc_contact = 1);
```

Comment: The reason I am using procedure to delete/update rows one by one to avoid locking.